# Implement a MasterDetailPage using FreshMVVM

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, freshmvvm

What is the right way to implement a master-detail page in FreshMVVM :

Checked different places but could not find a proper implementation for it,
This is my first time working on a xamarin forms application using MVVM as a whole.

Is there some sample code on GitHub or anything in similar to this? 
I have been trying for the whole day and still couldn't find anything relevant to my problem.

**PS: Asking for help after scratching my head for almost 2 Days**

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked the [sample app](https://github.com/rid00z/FreshMvvm/tree/master/samples/) in its Github page?

Comment: According to its documentation, in the sample app you can find:
"Tabbed Navigation with MasterDetail Popover Sample (This is called the CustomImplementedNav in the Sample App)"

Comment: will check it out and let you know

Comment: @Vahid it does not work as expected

Comment: Then you should ask FreshMvvm's developer for a sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like other people have suggested, I would look at the sample app on the Github page.

I also found a video that Michael Ridland (FreshMvvm creator) made a couple of years ago on navigation, which might help.

[FreshMvvm Navigation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JtSOUwtlgt0)